# java applet game jumping

Tags: java, applet

I'm quite new with Java and at the moment I'm making a super meat boy kinda game but I just can't figure out how to make him jump.

Here is the code I have so far, can anyone please describe me how to make him jump? Thanks.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class meatboy extends Applet implements KeyListener{
    public int x = 10, y = 300, gravity = 3;
    public int xs = 380, ys = 230;
    double jumptime = 0;
    public boolean right, left, up, jump, start, grounded;
    public void init(){
        setSize(800,400);
        setBackground(Color.black);
        addKeyListener(this);
        /////Movement//////
        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.schedule(new TimerTask(){public void run(){
        if (start == true){
        if (right == true){
            x = x + 3;
        }if (left == true){
            x = x - 3;
        }if(up == true && grounded == true){
            while(jumptime < 50){
                y--;
                jumptime = jumptime + 0.5;
            }
            grounded = false;
            jumptime = 0;
        }
        /////GRAVITY//////
        y = y + gravity;
        ///////Collision Dectection/////
        if(x > 790){//right of screen stop
            x = 10;
        }if(x < 10){// left stop
            x = 789;
        }if(y > 352){
            y = y - 3;
            grounded = true;
        }
        ////////////End of collision///////////
        repaint();
        }}},10,10);


        ///////movement end////////
        }
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        ////////CREATES MEATBOY///////////////
        if (start == false){
            x = 10; 
            y = 300;
            g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
            g.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 400);
            g.setColor(Color.white);
            g.drawString("MeatBoy 4K", 358, 180);
            g.drawString("Press Z to start!!!!", 350, 200);
            g.setColor(Color.RED);
            g.fillRect(xs, ys, 16, 16);//meatboys body
            g.fillRect(xs + 16, ys + 6, 4, 4);//arm
            g.fillRect(xs - 4, ys + 6, 4, 4);//arm
            g.fillRect(xs, ys + 12, 4, 6);//leg
            g.fillRect(xs + 12, ys + 12, 4, 6);//leg
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.fillRect(xs + 2, ys + 2, 5, 5);//eye
            g.fillRect(xs + 10, ys + 2, 5, 5);//eye

        }
        if (start == true){
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 16, 16);//meatboys body
        g.fillRect(x + 16, y + 6, 4, 4);//arm
        g.fillRect(x - 4, y + 6, 4, 4);//arm
        g.fillRect(x, y + 12, 4, 6);//leg
        g.fillRect(x + 12, y + 12, 4, 6);//leg
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(x + 2, y + 2, 5, 5);//eye
        g.fillRect(x + 10, y + 2, 5, 5);//eye
        ///////////END OF MEATBOY//////////////////
        ////////Creates Floor///////////////////
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 370, 800, 30);
        }
    }
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_Z){
            //right = true;
            start = true;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            //right = true;
            right = true;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = true;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up = true;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            up = true;
        }
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){
            //right = true;
            right = false;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
            left = false;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP){
            up = false;
        }if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            up = false;
        }
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

}
```

Comment: You might want to accept some of the answers in your two recent previous questions on this forum, and provide some comments and up-votes to the folks who volunteered their time and efforts trying to help you.

Comment: Please fix your shift key and apply it where appropriate (the start of sentences, the word 'I', abbreviations like ATM etc.).  Also try using some punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

When you jump you make a vertical change of 1 (up), however, your gravity makes a vertical change of -3 (down) and if getting too far down you reset the vertical position to ground level.

What you need to do is compensate for gravity when "jumping" and one way of doing it would be to use

```
while(jumptime < 50){
    y -= 1 + gravity;
    jumptime = jumptime + 0.5;
}
```

Comment: It's not quite `S=UT+.5AT^2` but it's a nice easy fix

Comment: Yes, I realize that the fix I gave did not mimic actual gravity, but currently the code had "gravity" as pulling down 3 every "tick", and a jump was up 1 every tick.

Comment: It wasn't a complaint-  your answer was appropriate and I +1'd - It was more a comment that this method of calculating motion is extremely limited. That said, I do remember those very first games which did this - Damn, now I've got to find my ATARI emulator.